# 2007 GE panel, I installed a 50 AMP GE double breaker on the bus for generator hookup.Inspector wants a hold down kit but ITS on the bus?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

The 50 AMP generator breaker is on a bus of a 2007 GE panel, all the back-fed GE breaker hold-down kits I can find are made for only the GE main breaker THQL-RK1, THQL-RK2, or THQL-RK4. Inspector is using the 2020 NEC 408.36 (D).

The 50 AMP breaker is on the right bus-tree below the main beaker, sorry I didn’t know how to explain it right. This is we’re the problem is, and yes I installed the inter-lock between the main and the generator 50AMP but the inspector wants a hold down kit which I don’t know if one is available for the tree breaker. Thanks for any help on this. I’m not by the house to get the panel details till Wednesday next week I work out of town

Comment: What's your question? The only question mark I see is on a _statement_ in your title. Please revise to be more clear. Take the [tour] for examples and tips.

Comment: On many GE panels the "main breaker" is a normal-looking breaker that is "on the bus" as you say.  You can tell because it's alongside the branch breakers.  That is the only kind of "main breaker" that needs a hold-down kit. All the main breakers that are different, have integral tie-downs.  So these kits may work for you after all. Consult your GE dealer.

Comment: Can you post photos showing both the breaker you installed *and* the label on the inside of the panel's door please?

Answer (score 4):

You *also* need a breaker interlock. Conveniently, GE offers a package that *includes* the actual interlock and a retainer (a.k.a., hold down) for the interlocked breaker. Such as [this one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-PowerMark-Gold-Load-Center-Generator-Interlock-Kit-THQLLX1/100674082):

[image: GE PowerMark Gold Interlock Kit]

I don't know if the parts are available separately. If they are, and you already bought the interlock itself, you may want to go back to where you bought it from to see if they can exchange it or sell you the retainer separately. If you didn't already buy the interlock, get the kit and you're all set. Double-check to make sure you get one compatible with your panel, as there may be a few different flavors. This one is specifically for:

> For use with a 150 - 225 Amp Powermark gold main breaker load center with a left-right handle orientation and a back-fed branch breaker mounted at top right

"2007" is not much of a description in the world of main panels.